# Reference chakra-ui custom colors in React components & theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm using [Chakra-UI](https://chakra-ui.com) for the first time, and extending the base theme. Following their [Scaling Out Your Project](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme#scaling-out-your-project) suggestion, I've broken things out into separate files and then include them, so I have:

```
//theme/index.js
import { colors } from 'theme/foundations/colors';

const overrides = {
  colors
};

export default extendTheme(overrides);
```

Then I have our broad color palette:

```
//theme/foundation/colors.js
export const colors = {
    myBlue: {
      50: '#e6f0ff',
      ...
      800: '#0b1e41', // My Blue
      900: '#010a1a'
    },
    myYellow: {
      50: '#fff4dc',
      ...
      400: '#f4a224', // My Yellow
      ...
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is name the specific hues:

```
//theme/foundation/colors.js
...
export const brand = {
  myBrand: {
    blue: colors.myBlue['800'],
    yellow: colors.myYellow['400'],
    clickable: colors.myYellow['400']
}
```

So I can do something like

```
//theme/global.js
a: {
  color: 'myBrand.clickable'
}
```

Doing it exactly like above doesn't work (it shows up in the rendered code in dev inspector as <s>`color: myBrand.clickable`</s> with an "Unsupported property value" warning.

If I instead reference it as a variable, like so:

```
//theme/global.js
import { brand } from './foundations/colors';

a: {
  color: brand.myBrand.clickable
}
```

it works as expected for styles applies from the theme (i.e., in the above case, all `<a>` elements are set to yellow), but I still can't access it as a chakra-named color in my React components. That is to say,

```
import { IconButton, useColorModeValue } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { BiMailSend } from 'react-icons/bi';

const MyButton = () => {
  return (
    <IconButton bg={useColorModeValue('myBrand.clickable', 'myBrand.clickable')}
      onClick={() => console.log('click')}
      icon={<BiMailSend />
  )
}
```

will render the icon, but not set the color. However, if I change 'myBrand.clickable' to a named Chakra color (e.g., either 'green', or 'green.400'), it works fine.

How do I set this up so I can use my own named colors both in the theme definition and in Chakra components throughout my code?

Answer (score 1):

For your **IconButton** to also color the icon you need to provide the attribute `colorScheme` not just the `bg`

Updated code:

```
import { IconButton, useColorModeValue } from '@chakra-ui/react';
```

import { BiMailSend } from 'react-icons/bi';

```
const MyButton = () => {
  return (
    <IconButton colorScheme={useColorModeValue('myBrand.clickable', 'myBrand.clickable')}
      onClick={() => console.log('click')}
      icon={<BiMailSend />
  )
}
```

Comment: This didn't exactly work. It did apply the color scheme to the component, but it didn't let me specify the named individual colors. Ended up just duplicating the definitions, rather than trying to get the named ones to inherit from base.